# How to fetch inside a webview in react native?

Tags: react-native, webview, fetch

I have a webview in a react native application. How can I perform a request (fetch, ajax, or others) inside the webview, using javascript?

This is the code in my webview

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      var init = { method: 'POST' };
      fetch(url, init)
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.blob();
        })
        .then(function (myBlob) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myBlob
        });
    </script>
    <p></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to inject js code into WebView:

```
<WebView
    ref={(ref) => { this.webview = ref; }}
    source={{ uri: this.state.webViewUrl }}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
    injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
    onMessage={this._onMessage} // only if you want connection back
/>
```

and you can pass `js` code - you can put your trigger anywhere you want, for the example, I call the action when the `button` clicked:

```
const jsCode = `
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", function() {  
        alert('Hello Web')
    }); 
    true;
    `
```

Comment: Idan, may I ask you something more? Its a doubt about how to make the fetch. How can I do in private?

Comment: Yeah sure, you can try to connect to my Linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/in/idan-levi-36899015a/

Comment: I couldn't do it through linkedin. I send you a message on facebook, I think

Comment: I didn't get your message, maybe try to ask your question and send me link here

Comment: i send you a message here fb.com/allan.cupertino